# Access gridview rows after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, templatefield

Good day!

I need to dynamycally upload files and display information in gridview.
After file upload, i need to select file type in dropdown. 
But after postback i can't access Gridview1 rows, and get selected file types. After postback Gridview1.Rows.Count = 0.

Is it possible to get selected values from DropDownLists?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" ShowHeader="False" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FileType">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="Val1">Val1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Val2">Val2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Val3">Val3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:CommandField DeleteText="Remove" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
```

Thanks

In Page_Load, during PostBack, GridView rows is empty.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     RestoreForm();

     if (IsPostBack && FileUpload.HasFile)
     {
         AddRow(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
     }

     FilesGridView.RowDeleting += new GridViewDeleteEventHandler(RemoveFileFromTable);
}

private void AddRow(string file)
{
     DataTable dt = (DataTable)Page.Session["Files"];
     if (dt == null)
     {
        AddDataTableToSession();
        dt = (DataTable)Page.Session["Files"];
     }
     DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
     dr["FileName"] = file;
     dr["FileType"] = 0;
     dt.Rows.Add(dr);
     Page.Session["Files"] = dt;
     FilesGridView.DataSource = dt;
     FilesGridView.DataBind();
 }

 private void AddDataTableToSession()
 {
     DataTable dt = new DataTable("Files");
     DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("FileName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
     dt.Columns.Add(dc);
     dc = new DataColumn("FileType", Type.GetType("System.String"));
     dt.Columns.Add(dc);
     Page.Session["Files"] = dt;
 }

 private void RemoveFileFromTable(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
 {
     int recordToDelete = e.RowIndex;
     DataTable dt = (DataTable)Page.Session["Files"];
     int cn = dt.Rows.Count;
     dt.Rows.RemoveAt(recordToDelete);
     dt.AcceptChanges();
     Page.Session["Files"] = dt;
     FilesGridView.DataSource = dt;
     FilesGridView.DataBind();
 }
```

Comment: What are you populating the GridView with? Can you show the code to populate the rows?

Comment: what's the difference between **KBFilesGridView** and **FilesGridView**?

Comment: No difference. Just mistake in text

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing Ispostback like this.

```
   if (!IsPostBack && FileUpload.HasFile)
   {
     AddRow(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
   }
```

(or)

```
   if (IsPostBack == false && FileUpload.HasFile)
   {
     AddRow(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
   }
```

So that, if page load occurs, Your if condition will get true.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the drop down list and update it with the value in the RowDataBOund event of gridview as follows

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //RestoreForm();

    if (IsPostBack && FileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        AddRow(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
    }
    else
    {
        AddDataTableToSession();
    }

    FilesGridView.RowDeleting += new GridViewDeleteEventHandler(RemoveFileFromTable);
    FilesGridView.RowDataBound += KBFilesGridView_RowDataBound;

}
```

and row databound will be as follows

```
    void KBFilesGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
            if (ddl != null)
            {
                DataRow dr= ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
                ddl.SelectedValue = dr["FileType"].ToString();
            }
    }
```

Similary you can get the value of dropdown for remove method as well as follows

```
private void RemoveFileFromTable(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
      if (ddl != null)
      {              
          if(ddl.SelectedValue == "someValue") doSomeThing();
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how i can take selected values of dropdown lists after postback?

Comment: Yes. There is no rows in GridView on RemoveFileFromTable.